# Installing Visual C# 2008 Express on Vista Business and UAC issue

Tags: c#, windows-vista, installation

I have just installed Visual C# 2008 Express edition onto Vista Business SP2 from a full iso download (Is about 1 GB with all 2008 Express editions). The install completes ok.

The problem I am having surely relates to some UAC issue. First there is a new link to "Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition" in the start menu. I click on it. Then Windows comes up with the "Searching for vcsexpress.exe" dialog because it can't find location of shortcut. I look at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0" (install directory) - and Windows pops up with "You don't have permission to access this folder. Click continue to access this folder". (So this is why Windows can't find the vcsexpress.exe - it's been hidden by security). If I alter the security eventually I can see a list of first child sub-directories, but this process does not work on the sub-directories. I simply get a message "You have been denied permission to access this folder".

How can I get past this? Why is this happening? I am logged on with an Administrator account!!

Any info/tips?

Thanks alot
Rael

Comment: Where did you even get this? VS2008 Express has been unavailable for almost 2 years now.  Don't trust *anything* from a random web site.

Comment: From Microsoft. Yes it was downloaded a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

UAC and default folder permissions in the Program Files directory does not prevent you from reading it's contents, only from changing it.

So if there is some file system security issue there, it might have to do with 3rd party utilities like virus scanners, and so on. Some security software prevents access to files which aren't authorised by the administrator first. (Not a very nice approach, IMHO).

Check your system and see if any of this kind of software is causing these issues.

Comment: Can you specify any such software? I am using AVG for anti-virus which as far as I know, does not do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the windows help, provide info on this issue:

> In some cases, you might not be able to view the object's security properties *even if you have administrative credentials*. This is because the object's security permissions do not grant the required access even to administrators. In this case, you need to take ownership of the object. For more information about taking object ownership, see Take Ownership of a File or Folder.

After "taking ownership" for the folder and all subfolders the problem was resolved.